# c++ expression must have class type?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a program as follows

```cpp
struct Musician {
    char code;
    int impact;
};

std::vector<Musician> aMuscian;

std::vector<Musician> readmuscianFile(std::string fileName)
{
    aMuscian.push( /*read file*/ );
    return aMuscican;
}

double overallbandPotential(std::string bandMembers)
{
    int totalPotential = 30;

    for (std::string s : Split(bandMembers, 2))
    {
        for (int i = 0; 10 > i; i++)
        {
            if (aMuscian[i].code.find(s.at(0)) != std::string::npos) {
                std::string num;
                num = s.at(1);
                int num1 = stoi(num);
                totalPotential += num1 * aMuscian[i].impact;
            }
        }
    }

    return totalPotential;
}}
```

The function overallbandPotential searches through the file and compares two text files against eachother( bands list of members(passed as a string) and the musicians code) if the codes match, then add it to the band potential

The issue with the program stems from this line

```cpp
if (aMuscian[i].code.find(s.at(0)) != std::string::npos)
```

This line produces the folllowing error at `aMusican[i]`
`std::vector<Musician> aMuscian expression must have class type`

Im unsure as to why this is occuring. If any extra code is required please feel free to ask. Thank you!

Comment: See the function `readmuscianFile`, change return type to `void` instead of `std::vector<Musician>`, otherwise you must return a vector from function

Comment: In `Musician` struct `code` is `char`, not `string` and `char` doesn't have method find

Comment: `aMuscian != aMusican` Please copy/paste the code and errors, do not retype them.

Comment: @armagedescu oh my bad i forgot to add the return value. Yes this is meant to return a vector

Comment: @dxiv This is due to me not being to spell correctly!! the error has indeed been copy/pasted

Comment: @pcv ah okay! woulld this be the source of my issue?

Comment: correcting my comment, In `Musician` struct `code` is `char`, not `string` and `char` is not `class` type, yes, that could be the issue

Comment: @pvc im a bit new so im not sure how to fix this? what would be a sugguested fix?

Comment: changing the `code` member from `char` to `string` ??

Comment: @pvc I wish it was that simple! unfortunately i cant as its for an assignment and the specs set it as a char

Comment: can you show us, how your bandMember string looks like? If I understand you correctly, `if bandMember.at(0) == code`, then run the code right?

Comment: And what you mean `bands list of members(passed as a string)` ??